# Map subset of taxonomy terms to a content type

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy called Writer and I have the terms added to it. I would like to maintain both active and inactive terms in the vocabulary and use only the active terms when mapped to a content type. In other words I would like to soft delete the terms instead of hard-deleting them. For this I added a custom boolean field for Writer vocabulary to indicate if the term is active or not. I am now not sure on how to apply the conditional mapping of taxonomy terms to the content type.

Appreciate help on this.

Comment: Just to add to this requirement, I need to display the writer for an article irrespective of the active flag. That means even the articles posted by inactive authors should be displayed in the website but the admin user should not be able to set the inactive authors for new content.   Is there a module or a hook which can help filter the terms based on the active flag in the Add/Edit content page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this using Taxonomy Publisher Filter which is part of [Taxonomy Tools](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_tools) module